# Not able to use feather-icons for divs constructed in JS files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, icons

I am using feather icons in a vanilla js project. When I am declaring the script `feather.replace()` inside the html body, the icons are coming correctly. However, I am creating certain div dynamically in JS. The icons aren't showing up inside those divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="wrapper>
    </div>

    <script>
      feather.replace()
    </script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

My js function:

```
let newInputWrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  newInputWrapper.innerHTML += `
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" class="input">
            <div class="input-icon font-color" id="${newAddID}" onClick="onAddNewCategory(this.id)">
                <i data-feather="plus"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-icon font-color" id="${newdeleteID}" onClick="onRemoveNewCategory(this.id)">
                <i data-feather="trash"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-icon font-color">
                <i data-feather="chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   `
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `feather.replace()` at the end of body to parse any dynamically-added element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="wrapper>
    </div>

    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
      feather.replace()
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```